# Browser navigation not loading component in Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a single-page application in Vue.js. Currently, navigation through the site works properly until you attempt to use the browser navigation buttons (back/forward).

When attempting to navigate with these no pages will be created. The URL will change but no components are loaded, unless you backup to the base URL where the component is loaded.

The templates are not loaded at all, I also have ESlint which shows no errors.

Here is my index.js for the router:

```
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'search',
      component: Search,
    },
    {
      path: '/results?terms=:terms',
      name: 'results',
      component: Results,
    },
    {
      path: '/review?id=:id',
      name: 'review',
      component: Review,
    },
  ],
});
```

I change pages by using: `this.$router.push({ name: 'results', params: { terms: this.terms } });`

I'm very new to Vue so I'm pretty sure I've just made a stupid mistake, but I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out so some help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: How are you _running_ your app?

Comment: I'm currently running it locally using npm run dev

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? How about the terminal / console where you're running `npm run dev`?

Comment: No errors/warnings in either location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that route params should not be passed as query string parameters. They are solely intended for use in the URL **path**.

For some reason, the router *is* able to handle programmatic navigation but not direct URL loading.

If you still want to use the query string (as opposed to path parameters), I suggest you change to something like this...

1. Define props for your components, eg

   ```js
   export default {
     name: 'Results',
     props: ['terms'],
     // etc
   ```
2. Pass the query string variables as props in your route definition

   ```js
   {
     name: 'results',
     path: '/results',
     component: Results,
     props: route => ({ terms: route.query.terms })
   }
   ```
3. Set `query` instead of `params` in your programmatic navigation

   ```js
   this.$router.push({ name: 'results', query: { terms: this.terms } })
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually just figured this out. Everything works now.

Comment: This solution still works.